# ssh service not running on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I run

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

and get

```
openssh-server is already the newest version.
```

Then I run

```
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

and it responds with

```
sshd.service
 Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
 Active: inactive (dead)
```

and yet it appears to be available

```
ssh -V
   OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first just try to remove then reinstall it.

```
sudo apt remove openssh-server
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: What do your logs say when you try to start it? (*grep ssh* when you tail your log)

Comment: Which logs should I be looking at?

Comment: ```sudo journalctl -f | grep sshd```

Comment: ```sudo journalctl -u sshd.service -f```

Comment: Thanks for your help. ssh service started with "sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start", "systemctl start ssh" says file not found. Maybe the version of Ubuntu needs to be upgraded. Any command with sshd fails.